# Time series of European sovereign credit ratings by the Big Three?

Tags: time-series, historical-data, credit-ratings

I would need time series, from 2000 to 2015 (if possible) of sovereign credit ratings by Moody's, S&P and Fitch.
Could you suggest me a source or provide me such a dataset?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Such data are provided by Bloomberg Terminal. I am positive about Moody's and S&P but not sure whether Fitch rating is also available.

Comment: I do not have access to Bloomberg, but I would need this data for  my master thesis. Do you have any idea how I could get them?

Comment: No I don't believe that you can find such data collectively on the internet for free.

Comment: Check with your library, they may not have bloomberg, but they may have other data providers such as Thomson Reuters (Eikon).